# Change Windows 11 TouchPad toggle programmatically

Tags: c#, windows

Although I searched this site and the internet I could not find any way to achieve enabling or disabling TouchPad programmatically for Windows 11. However this can be achieved easly via this page in settings:

[image: Windows 11 TouchPad settings]

Can anyone show me how to achieve this programmatically, preferably via C#.Net

**PS:** *I need this to affect immediately. I mean without a reboot or log out/log in.*

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tool for the job here? That's a global setting that belongs to the user. A single program shouldn't *want* to make changes to the user's settings.

Comment: Hi  Damien_The_Unbeliever. I could not understand what you mean exactly. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

**Backup your registry before making changes to it**

This registry key is the one to change (which you can change using c#).

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\Status`

You need to set the `Enabled` `REG_DWORD` to `0`

```
const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
const string subkey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\PrecisionTouchPad\\Status";
const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;
// ON
Registry.SetValue(keyName, "Enabled", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
// OFF
Registry.SetValue(keyName, "Enabled", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

You will then need to broadcast a message to tell Windows the setting has changed.

This is the `c#` (untested sorry). The documentation for the flags can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.unifiedservicedesk.dynamics.controls.nativemethods.sendmessagetimeoutflags?view=dynamics-usd-3

```
[Flags]
public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
{
    SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0,
    SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1,
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
    SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd,uint Msg,UIntPtr wParam,IntPtr lParam,
SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags,uint uTimeout,out UIntPtr lpdwResult);

IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
const uint WM_SETTINGCHANGE  = 0x1A;
const int MSG_TIMEOUT = 15000;
UIntPtr RESULT;
string ENVIRONMENT = "Environment";

SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(ENVIRONMENT), SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, MSG_TIMEOUT, out RESULT);
```

This is the `powershell` script

```
if (-not ("win32.nativemethods" -as [type])) {
    add-type -Namespace Win32 -Name NativeMethods -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
    IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, string lParam,
    uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);
"@
}

$HWND_BROADCAST = [intptr]0xffff;
$WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a;
$result = [uintptr]::zero

[win32.nativemethods]::SendMessageTimeout($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE,[uintptr]::Zero, "Environment", 2, 5000, [ref]$result);
```

Comment: Do you not have to broadcast a message after changing this registry value?

Comment: Hi Fawlty. I tried this but it did not affect without a restart. I need this without rebooting (or log out/log in). Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @AhmetErden, Anders is right. My answer is correct, but your best hope of no-reboot is to broadcast a message. I will update my answer now

Comment: Hi @Anders. Thank you for your reply. I tried both c# and powershell version of your codes to broadcast a message. Both return success (a non zero value) but does not affect at all.

Comment: Ahmet, have you tried closing and re-opening settings to see if it has picked up the change?